# WPF Data binding not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have built a window that has a xaml that looks like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level2">
        <Label Content="{Binding }" Width="70" Height="70" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" x:Name="Background">
        </Label>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="1">
                <Setter TargetName="Background" Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="5">
                <Setter TargetName="Background" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding }" Value="9">
                <Setter TargetName="Background" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=lst, Mode=OneWay}" Value="7">
                <Setter TargetName="Background" Property="Background" Value="blue"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level2}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel>
    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"  />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"  />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  x:Name="lst" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level1}"/>
        </Grid>

        <WrapPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Content="Start" Click="Start_Click" FontSize="15" MinHeight="30" MinWidth="90"/>
            <Button Content="Suggestion" Click="Suggestion_Click"  FontSize="15" MinHeight="30" MinWidth="90"/>
            <Button Content="Exit" Click="Back_Click"  FontSize="15" MinHeight="30" MinWidth="90"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Now I am getting all of the information in the "lst" from a 2D List that is stored in my Model. During run-time when I change a value in the List the changes do not appear in the Grid at all.

How can I make sure this happens?

This is the binding line in .cs

```
 viewModel.Command(gen);
 InitializeComponent();
 lst.ItemsSource = viewModel.VM_Maze;

public List<List<int>> VM_Maze
    {
        get { return model.Maze; }
    }
```

I dont know why changes in the List are not being reflected in the Gui. 
Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: Use ObservableCollection instead of List, lists will not inform about changes on it's content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First,

`VM_Maze` needs to be of type `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>>`.

Secondly, you're not binding anything in this line:

```
lst.ItemsSource = viewModel.VM_Maze;
```

You're just assigning it. Binding, as in `{Binding PropertyName}` in XAML, involves creating a [`Binding` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding(v=vs.110).aspx) instance which does a lot of helpful stuff for you.

This code will create an actual binding, that'll handle notifications and so on correctly:

```
Binding binding = new Binding { Source = viewmodel, Path = new PropertyPath("VM_Maze") };
BindingOperations.SetBinding(lst, ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

As you can see, it's much more convenient to bind in XAML. Your `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` doesn't do anything. *If* this object `viewmodel` is the actual `DataContext` for that view, then `ItemsSource="{Binding VM_Maze}"` should work.

Answer (score 0):

List does not inherit from INotifyCollectionChanged so it doesn't provide notifications when items are added or removed , why not use ObservableCollection instead 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx